# I want to create Simple XAML in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Here is the screenshot I want to create XAML in Xamarin Forms.

[image]

So what I want to know exactly is how can I place "62" to center in Parent and "PSI" next to "62".
It seems to need to use RelativeLayout but I can't create perfect same thing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, is a `Grid` with `Columns` and `Rows`

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Gray" Text="Healthy" />

        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Text="62" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Margin="0,10,0,0"  Text="PSI" TextColor="Gray" />
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Your image" />

    </Grid>
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the answer is something different with my expectation. so in your anwer "62 PSI" is in center of parent. But what I want is "62" is only in center and "PSI" is the right to it. It means Bold value should be shown in center.

Comment: I think @GeneraleXGR suggests a good approach. You should only remove PSI laberl from stacklayout and set it to Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" and set all the grid inside a fixed width and height frame (to have a square control)

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Your suggestion is not solution because if length of value is too long, it covers the "PSI".

Comment: I can do that in native IOS and Android but can't find the way in Xamarin Forms. it's so unhappy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Alessandro said, the GeralexGR answer it's a good aproach by using grid.
Take the next sample and modify it to your needs

```
<Grid Margin="20" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE">
        <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       Text="Healthy" TextColor="Gray"
                       FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       Text="62" TextColor="Black"
                       FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="PSI" TextColor="LightGray"
                       FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                       Source="hearth.png" />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
</Grid>
```

On the UI it will look like this
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PGz5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use RelativeLayout for this, but that's more complicated than you need for this.  The other answers suggest using a Grid, and that is the best answer here, but need a little different approach so that:

1. The "62" is perfectly centered.
2. The "PSI" is right after it, without a varying amount of space depending on screen size.

The Xamarin.Forms documentation for defining [Grid Rows and Columns](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/#Rows_and_Columns) lists three approaches (copied from Xamarin documentation):

- Auto – automatically sizes to fit content in the row or column. Specified as GridUnitType.Auto in C# or as Auto in XAML.
- Proportional(*) – sizes columns and rows as a proportion of the remaining space. Specified as a value and GridUnitType.Star in C# and as #* in XAML, with # being your desired value. Specifying one row/column with * will cause it to fill the available space.
- Absolute – sizes columns and rows with specific, fixed height and width values. Specified as a value and GridUnitType.Absolute in C# and as # in XAML, with # being your desired value.

The layout you want can be achieved with a 3x3 grid, where the center is Auto sized - that is its size is based on the content. Then the PSI Label can be in the same row, and the right-most column, so the spacing between them isn't dependent on screen size.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Gray" Text="Healthy" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="62" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="End"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="PSI" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="icon.png" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Aspect="AspectFit"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Frame CornerRadius="15" HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid Margin="-10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="17" Text="Healthy"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="6200" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalOptions="End" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="PSI" TextColor="Gray"  FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="iconHeart.png" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
```

[image]

- Take Frame for the Round Corner.
- Take Grid Inside it with 3 Columns & 3 Rows.
- 1st Row should Expand in all three columns, which contains Label with
  text "Healthy"
- Numeric Label goes in 2nd Row & 2nd Column to be in Center. It can
  take up to 4 digits without interrupting your UI.
- PSI is added in 2nd row & 3rd Column to put it besides Numeric Label.
- Image will go in 3rd Row, 3rd Column to be in right-bottom column.